# Umbraco admin shows "Not found" page for settings item after production update

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Everything works fine on local. When I uploaded the website to production, the website area works well but in admin area items under settings(Templates, CSS, etc.) have stopped opening and showing 404 page. I have checked the permissions and it is showing full control for both app pool and network service user.

Please suggest if I am missing something.
[image]

Comment: Have you checked if the paths (that Umbraco is pointing to) are actually the correct ones? Try installing Fiddler to see what's going on.

Comment: I checked in console and it shows 404 for /umbraco/settings/views/editview.aspx but how the main website works where the template has been used? Anyway what is the workaround?

Comment: I was just wondering if the backend was somehow pointing to an invalid path. That path looks fine, though. And you are sure the file (editView.aspx) exists on production server?

Comment: I checked, it exists there.

Comment: Had the same issue here.
Noticed that we use custom umbraco admin url, "{site}/manager", but the url presented for the EditView.aspx uses the default "{site}/umbraco".
Using http://localhost:84/manager/settings/Views/EditView.aspx?treeType=templates&templateID= manually worked. Looking for a solution now. Must be a miss config with this version.